Three simple(?) questions about proof of Lemma 10.18 in the John Lee's Riemannian manifold book.
I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold, Proof of the Lemma 10.18 and stuck at some statements :

Lemma 10.18. Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold with parallel curvature tensor, and for some points $p, \hat{p}\in M$ we are given a linear map $A: T_p M \to T_{\hat{p}}M$ satisfying $A^{*}(g_{\hat{p}})=g_p$ and $A^{*}(Rm_{\hat{p}})=Rm_{p}$. Then there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a local isometry $\varphi : U \to M$ such that $\varphi(p)=\hat{p}$ and $d\varphi_p=A$. If $M$ is complete, then $U$ can be taken to be any normal neighborhood of $p$.




( If needed, I will provide details except the underlined statements. )
I am now trying to understand the underlined statements.
Q.1. Why the curvature endomorphism is also parallel? Can anyone explain this more friendly, through showing concrete calculation?
Q.2. Why the second underlined statement is true? I think that we may use the Proposition 10.10 in the book :

Proposition 10.10 ( Jacobi Fields Vanishinig at a Point). Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian $n$-manifold and $p\in M$. Suppose $\gamma : I \to M$ is a geodesic such that $0\in I$ and $\gamma(0)=p$. For every $w\in T_pM$, the Jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ such that $J(0)=0$ and $D_t J(0)=w$ is given by $$ J(t)=d( \exp_p)_{tv}(tw),$$
where $v= \gamma'(0)$, and we regard $tw$ as an element of $T_{tv}(T_pM)$ by means of the canonical identification $T_{tv}(T_pM) \cong T_p M$.

In particular why $\hat{\gamma}$ is a geodesic?
Q.3. Why the third statement is true? Can anyone explain this derivation of differential equations more friendly? One of points that makes me stuck is, appearence of same symbols $v^jv^k$ in the first and second differential equations. As in the proof, $J$  is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$ and $\hat{J}$ is a Jacobi field along $\hat{\gamma}$. I think that $v^j$ (or $v^k$) are components of $\gamma'(t)$ with respect to the parallel orthonormal frame $(E_i)$ along $\gamma$ ( C.f. Proof of Proposition 10.2. in the John Lee's book. )..
Can anyone explain / teach these stuff more friendly? It will be very appreciated !

Q1: It is pretty much explained in the text, and it has nothing to do with the curvature tensor. Let e.g. $h = h_{ijk}$ be a $(0,3)$ tensor, and let ${h^{i}}_{jk}$ be the $(1, 2)$ tensor by raising the first index. That is, ${h^{i}}_{jk} = g^{il}h_{ljk}$. Then
$$\nabla_l {h^{i}}_{jk} = \nabla _l ( g^{im}h_{mjk}) = \nabla_l g_{im} h_{mjk} + g^{im} \nabla_l h_{mjk} = g^{im} \nabla_l h_{mjk}$$
since $\nabla g^{-1} = 0$ (this can be argued using $gg^{-1} = I$ and $\nabla g = 0$). Hence $h_{ijk}$ is parallel if and only if ${h^{i}}_{jk}$ is parallel.
Q2. I suggest you to go back and think about how the exponential map is constructed. It is more or less by definition that $t\mapsto \exp_p (tv)$, where $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, is a geodesic. See Proposition 5.19 in particular. And yes, that $\hat J$ is a geodesic follows from Proposition 10.10.
Q3. The book might not explain this clearly, but I think the idea is very obvious. They want to show $|\hat J (1)| = |J(1)|$ and to do this, one wants to use the uniqueness theorem of ODE to show that $\hat J$ is more or less the same as $J$. As stated this cannot be true, since $J, \hat J$ are vector fields along different curves. However, with an orthonormal frames they can be identified: as in the proof, let $\{E_1(t), \cdots, E_n(t)\}$ be a parallel vector field along $\gamma(t)$. Then $\gamma'(0)= v = v^i E_i(0)$. Since $\gamma$ is a geodesic, $\gamma'(t)$ is a parallel vector field along $\gamma$, hence
$$ \gamma'(t) = v^i E_i(t)$$
for all $t$ (the RHS of the above equation is parallel since each $E_i$ is, and it equals $\gamma'(0)$ at $t=0$. Hence the equality holds by Theorem 4.32 - the uniqueness of parallel transport). Similarly, write $J = J^i(t) E_i (t)$. Then since $D_t E_i = 0$,
$$ D_t J  = (J^i)' E_i ,\ \ \ D_t^2 J = (J^i)'' E_i.$$
Hence the Jacobi equation (10.1)
$$D_t^2 J + R(J, \gamma')\gamma' = 0$$
is given by
$$ 0= (J^l)''E_l + R (J^i E_i , v^j E_j) (v^k E_k) = (J^l)'' E_l + {R_{ijk}}^l J^i v^jv^k E_l.$$
hence
$$ (J^l)'' + {R_{ijk}}^l J_i v^jv^k = 0$$
for $l=1, \cdots, n$.
Now for $\hat J$: since $\hat v = Av$, we have
$$ \hat v = A ( v^i E_i (0)) = v^i A(E_i (0)) = v^i \hat E_i(0).$$
Since $\hat \gamma$ is a geodesic,
$$ \hat \gamma '(t) = v^i \hat E_i (t).$$
For the moment, define ${{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l (t)$ by
$$ R(\hat E_i (t), \hat E_j (t))\hat E_k (t) = {{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l (t) \hat E_l (t) .$$
Similar argument implies that ${{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l (t)$ is constant in $t$ and
$$ (\hat J^l)'' + {{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l \hat J_i v^jv^k = 0$$
for $l=1, \cdots, n$. It remains to show that ${{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l ={ R_{ijk}}^l$, and this follows from the assumption $A^* (Rm_{\hat p}) = Rm_p$: with this,
\begin{align}
 {\hat R}_{ijkl} (0) &= Rm _{\hat p} (\hat E_i (0), \hat E_j (0), \hat E_k (0), \hat E_l (0))\\
&= Rm _{\hat p} (A E_i (0), A E_j (0), A E_k (0), A E_l (0))\\
&=A^* (Rm _{\hat p}) (E_i (0), E_j (0), \hat E_k (0), \hat E_l (0)) \\
&= Rm_p (E_i (0), E_j (0), \hat E_k (0), \hat E_l (0)) \\
&= {R_{ijkl}} (0).
\end{align}
This implies ${R_{ijk}}^l (0) = {\hat R_{ijk}}^l (0)$ and hence ${{\hat R}_{ijk}}^l ={ R_{ijk}}^l$.

Thank you very much ! Can I ask more? Q.2. Going back to the question 2, $\hat{\gamma}$ is defined as $\hat{\gamma} (t) := \exp_{\hat{p}} ( t\hat{v})$ for $t\in [0,1]$. As you said, we may apply the Proposition 5.19 in John Lee's book. But $\exp_{\hat{p}} ( t\hat{v})$ is defined for all $t\in [0,1]$? ; i.e., $\gamma_{ t \hat{v}}$ is defined on an interval containing $[0,1]$  for each $t\in [0,1]$?

And If you have time, can I ask further more about the proof , since as I read, more new questions arose? Q.4. In the first paragraph of the proof, he wrote, " If $M$ is complete, let $U$ be any normal neighborhood of  $p$." How arbitrary normal neighborhood works for subsequent proof? Where the completeness of $M$ is used?

And Q.5. In the third paragraph of the proof, he wrote, $0 = (D_t R)(E_i(t), E_j(t))E_k(t)$. I convinced from explanation about first question that $\nabla R =0 $. But why  $0 = (D_t R)(E_i(t), E_j(t))E_k(t)$? Am I missing something?

Anyway I impressed your kind explanation. Thank you :)
